# How to remove element from ConfigSections in .NET 4.5

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

Using .NET 4.5, I need to remove section names from the  section in my web.config file (these are settings being added in the config file for another asp.net application) just as described in this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228258%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

However, the  element doesn't seem to be available anymore in .NET 4.5. How do we accomplish this now?

Thanks,

Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't aware it was removed.  If it actually was then the only two ways to do it are:

Use the [.NET api to modify the configuration file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151456%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or use [web config transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which can be used to remove entries on deployment.